# C++ stack variables and heap variables

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

When you create a new object in C++ that lives on the stack, (the way I've mostly seen it) you do this:

```
CDPlayer player;
```

When you create an object on the heap you call `new`:

```
CDPlayer* player = new CDPlayer();
```

But when you do this:

```
CDPlayer player=CDPlayer();
```

it creates a stack based object, but whats the difference between that and the top example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference is important with PODs (basically, all built-in types like `int`, `bool`, `double` etc. plus C-like structs and unions built only from other PODs), for which there is a difference between *default initialization* and *value initialization*. For PODs, a simple

```
T obj;
```

will leave `obj` uninitialized, while `T()` default-initializes the object. So

```
T obj = T();
```

is a good way to ensure that an object is properly initialized.

This is especially helpful in template code, where `T` might either a POD or a non-POD type. When you know that `T` is not a POD type, `T obj;` suffices.

***Addendum:*** You can also write

```
T* ptr = new T; // note the missing ()
```

(and avoid initialization of the allocated object if `T` is a POD).

Comment: User-defined types can also be PODs, in which case they will behave like built-ins when no explicit initialization is done.

Comment: @Konrad: You're right, the distinction is between PODs and non-PODs! Thank you for pointing this out, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: In C++0x, you can ensure proper initialization with `T obj{};`.

Comment: There some other differences... `T obj = T()` requires that the copy constructor is available (even if the compiler will elide the copy).

Comment: @FredOverflow: Doesn't this declare a function?

Comment: @David: Yes, that's right. However, I'm not sure it's relevant enough for the question to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

> When you create a new object in C++ that lives on the stack, (…) you do this:
>
> ```
> CDPlayer player;
> ```

Not necessarily on the stack: variables declared in this way have *automatic storage*. Where they actually go depends. It may be on the stack (in particular when the declaration is inside a method) but it may also be somewhere else.

Consider the case where the declaration is inside a class:

```
class foo {
    int x;
};
```

Now the storage of `x` is where ever the class instance is stored. If it’s stored on the heap, then so is `x`:

```
foo* pf = new foo(); // pf.x lives on the heap.
foo f; // f.x lives where f lives, which has (once again) automatic storage.
```

Comment: @Tony: Does this really answer the question? It was rather meant as a supplementary comment …. It doesn’t touch the difference between your first and third code at all, since other answers have already done that.