# How I can create object in register in CUDA?

Tags: c++, object, memory, cuda

I have some class

```
class A {
int bla;
float blabla;
};
```

Is there any way to create object `A` in **registry of thread** ? Because, `new` and `malloc` are allocating space in **global memory** (which I don't want to do).

Comment: If you create A on the thread stack then the compiler will allocate space on the stack but the members may always be in registers. If you new A then it will be on the context heap in global memory.

Comment: "create A on the thread stack" - Ok, so how the code will look like in kernel method?

Comment: In your thread code, do: `A myA;`   Then myA is an immediate or stack variable.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735839/c-stack-variables-and-heap-variables).

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not comments.  The CUDA "unanswered questions" percentage is rising...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **local** variable in a kernel is **allocated** in the **register file** of the GPU. Unless you have already used all registers. The register file usage is handled automatically so you can't do much about it but change your code and check the usage with compiler flag: `--ptxas-options=-v`. When the register file is full the data is spilled out to the cache L1, if enabled. Otherwise the data goes in cache L2.

Example kernel would be:

```
__global__ regKernel(int length)
{
 A localA; // goes to register file
 int threadId = threadIdx.x;// goes to register file
 if (threadId < length)
 {
   localA.bla++;
   localA.blabla = 0.4;
 }
}
```