# Why the Block is different in OC and c++?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, block

I defined a block with this code：

```
void(^blockA)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"just a block");
};
NSLog(@"%@", blockA);
```

it's print:

```
DeepCopy[22740:832979] <__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x100002150>
```

this print show the block is global block, but when I clang it to c++ code, it show this block is a stack block with above code:

```
struct __main_block_impl_0 {
   struct __block_impl impl;
   struct __main_block_desc_0* Desc;
   __main_block_impl_0(void *fp, struct __main_block_desc_0 *desc, int flags=0) {
      impl.isa = &_NSConcreteStackBlock;
      impl.Flags = flags;
      impl.FuncPtr = fp;
      Desc = desc;
   }
};
```

why the block is different?

Comment: Because of OC is not C++. I think so

Comment: Objective-C is mainly using heap and C++ is more likely using stack. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735839/c-stack-variables-and-heap-variables

Comment: @cekisakurek oc clang to c++，the implementation code is change?

Comment: The thing is that block seems a stack variable. i.e not a global var or property so I assume while converting to c++ compiler choose to use stack.

Comment: what do you mean "when I clang it to c++ code"? do you mean you used the clang rewriter? because the rewriter often does not produce the same code as the compiler